# View will not display taxonomy location information

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, location

I have a taxonomy that contains information about event venues. I am using the location module to add locative information to these taxonomy terms.

I've created a view so that I can see all my venues and their location information, but the location information is not appearing in the view.

Here's a screenshot of the view I have built, but the location information does not appear!
[image: View Settings for Taxonomy List]

Each term has its location info filled in:
[image: As you can see I have updated location information for this taxonomy term]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great answer, but I do have an answer.

For some reason, Views isn't pulling this data. I've been unable to get a clean install of Drupal 7, views, location to pull this info when entered in the Location fieldgroup on a taxonomy term.

I HAVE been able to create a custom field for the location via 'manage fields', and THAT will appear in Views.

I hope that helps you (and anyone else looking at this!)